# Is it safe to pass a null pointer to ippsFree?

Tags: c, intel-ipp

[Intel Document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/502012) only describes ptr passed in should point the space allocated from ippsMalloc. It does not say anything what happened if we pass a null pointer in it.

```
void ippsFree(void* ptr);
```

> ptr Pointer to a memory block to be freed. The memory block pointed to
>   with ptr is allocated by the function ippsMalloc.

Is it safe like free/delete accept null pointer? or is it undefined?

Comment: Well, you'd ultimately have to ask intel about that, but it would be IMHO quite brain-dead to provide alternative `malloc()`/`free()` implementations with different semantics from the standard library ones **without** explicitly documenting this. So my *guess* is it's safe.

Comment: Actually I met a problem when I try to register on Intel Developer Zone for posting on forum, so I post here. Maybe someone may have the same question like me. I am afraid there is additional processing in ippsFree that assumes the ptr is non-null.

Comment: This [code example](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504353) on the Intel site uses `ippsFree` to free two pointers when the allocation of at least one of them nas failed and is `NULL`. So according to this example, it is safe to pass `NULL`.

Comment: If the official example demonstrates how to allocate/free the memory like it, it may be safe to pass null pointer in. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just try it out in a noddy program.  If it misbehaves, then you know it is not safe.

Comment: Fine on my platform does not mean ok on other platform. Maybe it is just lucky not crash on my testing case.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the dis-assembly of ippsFree function, the functions tests the argument (pointer) upon entry.
It is safe to use NULL pointer.